# How to write Python's super() call at the end of an __init__ block in C#?

Tags: c#, python, inheritance

I've been porting a lot of Python code over to C# and regularly come across a `super().__init__` call at the end of an `__init__` block in Python. The problem comes in when some python code in a derived classes `__init__` block does something before calling a base constructor. In C#, it's assumed that the base constructors are required for the derived constructors to work, and they are called first, before "stuff" is done in the derived constructor. My usual workaround was to write up a static method and call that inside of base (Ex. `public C : base( DoStuff(someVariable) )`. That worked okay when I had one argument base constructors. But what if I have three arguments? I don't want to repeat the `__init__` block code three times using three different static methods, so instead I wrote one method that returns the first argument and also sets the other arguments in local variables.

Is there a better way to accomplish doing stuff to two+ variables in a derived constructor before passing the results up to a base constructor in C#?

Here is some testing code I wrote to observe the behavior of my workaround:

```
using System;

namespace BaseSuperTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Main...");
            var B = new B(0,0,"zero");

            Console.WriteLine();

            var C = new C();
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public A(int first, int second, string third)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tIn A's constructor...");
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0} {1} {2}", first, second, third);
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public static int Second { get; set; }

        public static string Third { get; set; }

        private static int DoStuff(int first, int second, string third)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tIn DoStuff()...");
            Second = second + 1;
            Third = "changed";
            return first + 1;
        }

        public B(int first, int second, string third) : base(DoStuff(first, second, third), Second, Third)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tIn B's constructor...");
        }
    }

    class C : B
    {
        public C() : base(0,0,"zero")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tIn C's constructor...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you must initialize fields in your derived before you initialize the base, that smells like design problem. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I agree entirely with the design being far from ideal. Part of the problem is that I'm porting from such a huge code-base, that right now I'm just trying to replicate behavior without changing too much of the design. So, for now, I need a derived class to be able to do stuff to args passed into it before calling a base class constructor with those now modified arguments.

Comment: I understand that a large code base can be problematic to port. But, if you don't have a high level design in mind, you're just going to be doing one patch over the other, which i'm not sure will result in any better code. I don't know why you're porting your code, but I don't think you want to end up with *less* maintainable code than what you already have.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I will talk to my team about this issue because I agree that we don't want less maintainable code. The goal is to have more manageable code with higher test coverage. In the mean-time, I want to at least make sure that my workaround works. I will be looking into a better design pattern with my team as well.